# how to update an attribute in a nested array object DynamoDb AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I want to update the choices attribute directly through AWS API Gateway.

```
{
    "id" : "1",
    "general" : {
        "questions : [
             "choices" : ["1","2","3"]
         ] 
     }
}
```

Here is my resolver mapping template

```
#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))

{
    "TableName" : "models",
    "Key" : {
        "accountId" : {
            "S": "$inputRoot.accountId"
        },
        "category" : {
            "S" : "model"
    }
},
"UpdateExpression" : "SET general.questions = :questions",
"ExpressionAttributeValues" : {
    ":questions" : {
        "L" : [
            #foreach($elem in $inputRoot.questions)
            {
                "M" : {
                    "choices" : {
                        "L" : [
                            #foreach($elem1 in $elem.choices)
                            {"S" : "$elem1"}
                            #if(foreach.hasNext),#end
                            #end
                        ]
                     }
                  }
               }
               #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
               #end
           ]
       }
    
    }    
}
```

But I am getting Internal server error 500 on execution.

```
 Gateway response body: {"message": "Internal server error"}
```

Does DynamoDb support updating this expression or is there any error in mapping template ? If so what should be the mapping template for the object I am trying to update.

Comment: The expression looks correct, and I'm not familiar with this "mapping template" syntax, but in any case if you have a syntax error or something, DynamoDB normally returns a 400 code with a nice textual explanation of the problem - not this generic "500 Internal server error", so this is very strange. Do simpler requests work for you? Can you use wireshark or something to look at what the HTTP request that leave your client actually looks like?

Comment: Indeed - "Gateway response body" is related to the API gateway and " "Internal server error" is the generic error aws throws when the lambda has an issue.